# How can I use Intellij refactoring to replace "System.out" calls with logging?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A legacy application has 3000+ calls to System.out.

Using Intellij's refactoring tools, how can I (easily) replace calls to  "System.out" with a calls to log4j/java.util.logging/etc?

I've poked around the refactoring menu but didn't see any options.

Note: I know i can use 'source code find/replace' , but was curious if the refactoring tools handled this type of usecase

thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it could be possible to also add a Logger field to classes which contain calls to System.out, so the code does not get broken... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

to add a Logger to each Class you could use:

```
class $Class$ {
   $Content$
}


class $Class$ {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log =  Logger.getLogger($Class$.class);
    $Content$
}
```